# How To Use Sub Domain Assets for another Sub Domain

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, font-face

I have Two sub-domains in my Wamp-server

- http://management.localhost
- http://asset.localhost

in My Asset.localhost . I have **css folder** and , in this folder I have **style.css** file that contains  **@fontFace**  like Below Code :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'yekan';
    src: url('../fonts/Yekan-modified.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/Yekan-modified.eot#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/Yekan-modified.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/Yekan-modified.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/Yekan-modified.svg#CartoGothicStdBook') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

- My font folder path is http://asset.localhost/admin/fonts/[MYFONTS]
- My css folder path is http://asset.localhost/admin/css/style.css

Now I'd like to use this file **(style.css)** to http://management.localhost/dashbord/index.php

Css codes works as well But Fonts Doesn't work !
  **Where is My Mistake ?**

**Thank You...**

Answer (score 1):

just specify full fonts path in your css file

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'yekan';
    src: url('http://asset.localhost/admin/fonts/Yekan-modified.eot');
    src: url('http://asset.localhost/admin/fonts/Yekan-modified.eot#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('http://asset.localhost/admin/fontsYekan-modified.woff') format('woff'),
     url('http://asset.localhost/admin/fontsYekan-modified.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('http://asset.localhost/admin/fontsYekan-modified.svg#CartoGothicStdBook') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

since `..` specifies its parent directory but your fonts is in other directory so specifying full path will solve it

Comment: Thank you for answer But i tried this Way Before Your answer and doesn't work